# How to disable the dojo button with click event

Tags: button, dojo, click

I need to disable the dojo button with click event, But my dojo button disable color only button now also click event working properly, how to restrict this? In j query when we use the disable attribute the click vent also change to the disable mode. How its in dojo?

My code:

```
 dom.byId("somID").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to work with the widget and not the dom node.

```
require(['dijit/registry'], function(registry) {
    registry.byId('somId').set('disabled', true);
});
```